# How to get value of inputs onChange when they are inside map function

Tags: reactjs

I would like to get the values of some input on change when they are inside a map loop function. This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ArrayComponent extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { objects: [] };
 }

  handleChange(index, id, e) {

  // what to put here ?
  // want to have a state like :
  // [{index: e.target.value, key: id}, {index: e.target.value, key: id}, ...]

   }
 render() {
  return (
     <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          {item.name}
          <input
            key={index}
            value={this.state.objects[index]}
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, index, item.id)}
          />
      </div>
    ))}
       <Button>
         Update 
       </Button>
     </Form>
    );
  }
  }

  export default ArrayComponent;
```

I want to have a state like :
`[{index: e.target.value, id: id}, {index: e.target.value, id: id}, ...]` It means that If they are four inputs I want to have a state like above for four inputs.

Comment: where does "items" come from? i dont see it as a prop or anywhere on the code.

Comment: it comes from props. It should be `this.props.items.map ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { objects: {} };
}

handleChange(event, index, id) {
   this.setState((state) => {
    const newObject = {...state.objects};
    newObject[`${index}`] = {value: event.target.value, key: id}
    return {objects: newObject }
   });
}

render() {
  return (
     <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div>
          {item.name}
          <input
            key={item.id}
            value={this.state.objects[`${index}`]?.value || ''}
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, index, item.id)}
          />
      </div>
    ))}
       <Button>
         Update 
       </Button>
     </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

You should avoid setting map `index` values as component keys.  So I removed index and just used the item id as the key prop.

---

#### Edit - Removed index

You can remove index all together:

```
handleChange(event, id) {
   this.setState((state) => {
    const newObject = {...state.objects};
    newObject[`${id}`] = {value: event.target.value, key: id}
    return {objects: newObject }
   });
}

//........

value={this.state.objects[`${item.id}`]?.value || ''}
onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, item.id)}
```

Comment: I get an error like : `this.state.objects["".concat(...)] is undefined` . I think it the `value` of input.

Comment: try this `value={this.state.objects[`${index}`]?.value || ''}` @Tjax

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, it works with `id` but does not work with `index` why? I accept ur answer anyway.

Comment: if you defined index in both the function declaration and were you retrieve that value ``${index}``, I really don't see why it shouldn't work.  `Console.log(index)` in the `handleChange` to see what value you are receiving.

Comment: I get `object` instead of `number` when I put `index` there?

Comment: That is why it does not work with index

Comment: and you aren't using `index` anywhere else?  You get an object in the `console.log()` inside handleChange?  maybe a typo somewhere, but should 100% be a number.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: It works now, My mistake I did not pass index to `handeChange`. Thanks again for ur answer